# Вывести на экран сумму чисел массива с помощью циклов while

Tags: java, циклы, while

```
`package com.example.laba12;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class Laba12 {  
                    public static void main(String[] args) {  
                        int Sum = 0;  
                        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  
                        int[]a= new int[10];  
                        int i=0;  
                        System.out.println("Введите элементы массива");  
                        while ( i < 10) {  
                            a[i]=s.nextInt();  
                            Sum=Sum+a[i];  
                            i++;  
                        }  
                        System.out.println("Сумма ="+Sum);  
                    }  
                }
```

`Не подскажите, в чем заключается моя ошибка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в том что 0 вместо суммы

Comment: Добавте код как текст вместо картинки.

Comment: while( i < 10) {
a[i] = s.NextInt();
Sum += a[i];
i++;
}

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, ошибка в том, что код приведен в скриншоте.
Во-вторых, вы инкрементируете `i` до того, как добавляете `a[i]` в сумму.
Таким образом в выражении `sum=sum+a[i]` `a[i]` всегда равно 0, кроме последней итерации - там происходит выход за границы массива. Если бы вы воспользовались отладчиком, не пришлось бы задавать тут вопрос.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь,отредактировал код и написал его не в самом вопросе.